# How do I verify if I'm using the native iOS SQLite provider, and how do I correct it?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, nuget, visual-studio-mac, sqlite-net

I'm using a new project that's using `sql-lite-pcl` and it doesn't appear to be loading the required dependency packages (recursively). I know this because "it just doesn't work (tm)"

I've been able to get the project to work by adding the following on the Xamarin Forms project and the iOS project

- SQLite-net-pcl
- SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green
- SQLitePCLRaw.core
- SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.ios
- SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl
- SQLitePCLRaw.provider.internal.ios_unified. (iOS only)
- SQLitePCLRaw.provider.ios_inified (iOS only)

For most of the items above I needed to install a 1x version, whereas the 2.0 version of SQLite reported a variety of errors from the SQLite-net-pcl library. (there is an open GIT issue on the project page for 2.0 support)

**Question**

1. How do I verify (in runtime?) that I'm using the native iOS provider?
2. Does it matter if I switch between the iOS provider and the code- based one? In either data binary reading and writing, locks, app suspension/closing handles, performance or any other reason?
3. What are the correct libraries to load if simply adding sql-lite-pcl into a Visual Studio for Mac doesn't recursively load all dependencies, and the correct version of them?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good tutorial how to use SQLite for Xamarin Forms. [You can find it here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm)

It's working fine both for Android and iOS version